# Projeto de API e XAMARIN

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, arquitetura-de-software

Pessoal tenho uma Solution onde estar toda a arquitetura para exposição da minha API.
O projeto que ira consumir esta API sera em XAMARIN.
Minha dúvida é: Eu devo criar dentro da solution este projeto ou em uma outra solution?

Creio que no futuro outras pessoas iram desenvolver no Xamarin e não queria que outras pessoas tivessem acesso a estrutura do projeto de API.

Existe alguma outra solução para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, você mesmo já respondeu à sua pergunta.

Crie uma outra solução para o projeto em `Xamarin`, que muito provavelmente não terá nada o que reutilizar da sua `API`.
A única coisa que ele deverá fazer é **consumir** os serviços que estiverem sendo expostos por ela publicamente, assim como qualquer outra aplicação cliente também poderá fazê-lo (se isso estiver dentro dos seus planos).

Aqui estão alguns motivos que reforçam o fato de o projeto cliente (nesse caso em xamarin) deve estar em outra solução:

- Não será reaproveitado código da sua solução atual, uma vez que eles devem ter naturezas, objetivos e talvez até escopos distintos;
- Os serviços da sua API e o projeto xamarin seguem linhas evolutivas completamente diferentes e não necessariamente relacionadas;
- Como você já informou, serão equipes diferentes que irão lidar com cada uma das soluções;
- Seria uma exposição desnecessária de recursos de um projeto no outro, enchendo de 'lixo' o desenvolvimento na sua IDE;
- Mesmo sendo possível, é muito pouco provável que você vá querer executar os dois projetos (api e app) de modo que eles estejam se comunicando durante os desenvolvimentos/testes.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento.Precisava destes motivos para poder sanar a dúvida.